# Взаимодействие с SharePoint с подключенной 2FA через SharePoint CSOM

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, 2fa

Всем привет. Нужно написать либу для работы с шарпоинтом. Столкнулся с проблемами уже на этапе подключения к шарпоинту. Вот такой эксепшен получаю:

```
Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) did not get a response from the Login server.
```

Я предполагаю, что это происходит из-за того, что на шарпоинте подключена 2FA. Для 2FA используется microsoft authenticator. Вот код, который у меня есть:

```
public class SharePointHandler
{
    private ClientContext clientContext;

    public SharePointHandler(string siteUrl, string username, string password)
    {
        var SPOCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, ToSecureString(password));
        clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

        clientContext.Credentials = SPOCredentials;
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // тут падает исключение
    }

    private static System.Security.SecureString ToSecureString(string password)
    {
        System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password)
            secureString.AppendChar(c);

        return secureString;
    }
}
```